# UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, utf-8, encode

How do I handle this?

wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character

```
import tweepy
import time
import os
import json

search_term1 = '' 
search_term2 = ''  

lat = ""
lon = ""
radius = ""
location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)  

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)      

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
            q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term1, search_term2),   
            rpp=1000,    
            geocode=location, 
            include_entities=True)


wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/test1.txt", mode='w')   
data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():            

    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')  
    time.sleep(0.5)                 
    i += 1

wfile.close()
```

I get this error by modifying the Internet.

TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments

```
wfile.write(data['text']+'\n',encoding='UTF8')
```

TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

```
 wfile.write(data['text']+'\n','utf-8')
```

Answer (score 4):

`cp949` is the default locale for your Windows system, and that's what `open()` defaults to. From the [`open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns), but any text encoding supported by Python can be used.

Specify a different codec when opening the file:

```
wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/test1.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf8')
```

Note that you don't need to pre-pend `os.getcwd()` when opening a file without a path, the default is to use the working directory for relative paths:

```
wfile = open("test1.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf8')
```

You'd be better off using `os.path.join()` to build paths for everything else.

Your code can otherwise be simplified further with `enumerate()` and a context manager. The `data` dictionary is not really useful here, just reference `tweet.text` everywhere:

```
with open(os.getcwd()+"/test1.txt", mode='w') as wfile:
    for i, tweet in enumerate(c.items()):
        print("{}: {}".format(i, tweet.text))
        wfile.write(tweet.text + '\n')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```