# UnicodeEncodeError 'cp949' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

When I run a python program on Anaconda prompt, I got an error message with "UnicodeEncodeError 'cp949' codec can't encode character \u2022' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence",
and the just previous message was 'File 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py', line 155, in writerow 
return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))

People say I should use UTF-8 when I read and write a file. 
I think I should insert a certain command in the "myprogram.py" when I run 
'python myprogram.py' on Anaconda prompt.
What should I do?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? I'm guessing from the error message it's Python 3. Ideally, you should set up your system to use UTF-8 instead of cp949, but I believe that can be tricky on Windows.

Comment: @PM 2Ring It&amp;#39;s Python 3 and Windows 7

Comment: @PM 2Ring Python 3 Windows 7

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Windows, but there's some good info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821262/unicodeencodeerror-cp949-codec-cant-encode-character

Comment: There are quite a few questions here about encoding issues... The point is: there's no "magic" solution to encoding problems, you have to spend some time understanding what unicode is, what encodings are, and how to use them. You can start here : https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers I know what encoding is. The issue is how I can apply UTF8 encoding in the entire program

Comment: Hard to say without a [mcve]. But the error message says that `writer.writerow` could not write a bullet (• or `'\u2022'`) because it uses a cp949 encoding. Is it a plain file or a console? Solutions will be different in Windows...